# ZeroMQ blocked in a context.term() call. Why? How to prevent?

Tags: java, zeromq

I have a java program that using ZeroMQ.

But I found the program blocked in `context.term();` if receiving a `message( recvMsg() )` time out!

```
ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);  
ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);  
socket.connect(mAddress);         

ZMsg ZM = new ZMsg();
ZM.add(qString);
ZM.send(socket, true);

socket.setReceiveTimeOut(mTimeout);     
ZMsg receivedZM = ZMsg.recvMsg(socket);

if(receivedZM != null) {
    System.out.println(receivedZM.getFirst().toString());   
}      
socket.close();  
context.term();
```

What is the reason cause it to blocked?

And how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ZeroMQ is a system using many tricks behind the `Context()`-factory

I always advocate to automatically set **`.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER, 0 )`** right upon a Socket-instantiation, right due to these types of behaviour, that otherwise remain outside of your local-code domain of control. A hanging `Context`-instance IO-thread(s) ( be it after a programmed `.term()` having been issued in spite of the not yet successful `.close()` of all `socket`-instances, instantiated under this `Context`-instance the `.term()` is to dismantle and release back all system resources from, or an unhandled exception case, when things just went straight wreck havoc ) is one of such never-more-s.

Feel free to follow schoolbook and online hacks/snippet examples, but a serious distributed system designer ought take all reasonable steps and measures so as to prevent her/his system code to fall into any deadlock-state ( the less into an un-salvageable one ).

---

### What is the reason?

As documentation states - it is a designed-in feature of ZeroMQ:

> attempting to terminate the socket's context with `zmq_ctx_term()` shall block until all pending messages have been sent to a peer.

Any case, where a `.send()`-dispatched ( just dispatched -- by no means meaning that it has already been sent-to-wire ) message is still inside the local-queue for any of the recognised ( and potentially disconnected or busy or ... ) peer-nodes, the just-default configured `.term()` cannot proceed and will block.

---

### What is the solution:

Newer API versions started to say, a default `LINGER` value to stop being **`-1 == INFINITY`**, but as you never know, which version will your code interface with, an explicit ( manual ) call to a `.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER, 0 )` method is a self-disciplining step and increases your team awareness on how to build reliable distributed-systems' code.

Using the `try: / except: / finally:` syntax-handlers is needless to be raised here. You simply always have to design with failures & collisions in mind, haven't you?

Comment: Setting LINGER to 0 is an excellent idea. I'm going to start doing that myself. As fulsome an answer as there ever was, excellent.

Comment: An ***idea ;)*** ??? **Would rather call it a Must-Do step, a truly LIFE-SAVING JACKET.** In all pieces of my work.

Comment: Actually some of the binding already do that by default (CZMQ and NetMQ as far as I know)

Comment: Yes, somdoron, the newest API has changed the initial default of -1, but any professional distributed-system designer's mental practice ought be defensive, so as to enforce it, irrespective of the ( currently might be temporally somewhat friendlier ) default, so as to avoid deadlocks in case the code is not being run with matching API-version. That sounds legitimate, doesn't it?. Bindings per se are absolutely uncertain as how these happen to indeed start to reflect the most recent API changes. Got many issues with the black-box part of the binding / wrapper design once interfacing creeped.

Comment: It helps a lot! thanks! However, it seems no corresponding function like  setsockopt() in Java binding. Is there any alternative way to solve this issue?

Comment: Check how Java-binding implements .setsockopt() to setup a SUB-side subscription / aTopicFILTER. There such a call must appear. Anyway, Java-binding maintainers are the right place to ask, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API, http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-term, it will block when there's still messages to transmit. This suggests that you other machine or process, the one that will open the REP socket; isn't running.

Comment: Thanks~ But I still don't understand. Since the recvMsg() already time out(otherwise program will still block at recvMsg()) there should be no message to transmit.
And since the "context" object is created within the program, would it be affected by other process or machine?

Comment: with zmq api you have to close all sockets before close context (at least created in thread from which you call zmq_term). It is possible implement track all sockets in context object and close them automatically. But have no idea is it implemented in pyzmq.